# Using .json files as configuration in react application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

What is the right way to get configuration work in react? Actually, I would like to use .json file(-s) for configuration purposes but it is not must.
Somebody suggests changing webpack.config.js to show webpack where the additional configuration is, but in create-react-app I don't have access to this configuration file.

Comment: hey did you ever get through with this ? Using some json file to configure webpack / application defaults ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't "use" react to get data from an API. React is just the view component. You can use javascript to make HTTP calls to get the data from your API. If you are doing a lot with data then I recommend looking into flux/redux/alt. There are plenty of http libraries to use out there. I like using [github.com/mzabriskie/axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) or you can even just use $.get(apiUrl, function(data) {});

Comment: That's what I am doing: `$.get(apiUrl, function(data) {})` but the question is where to store this `apiUrl` value, I don't want it to be hard coded.